# Number Theory -- Sieve Method Question

Tags: number-theory, sieve-theory

I'd like help with this problem:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wp0mg.png)

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: Okay, I'm new here. How do I write math? LaTeX?

Comment: See [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).